# Weblogic maven plugin with ssl problem

Tags: plugins, ssl, maven, weblogic

I am now trying to use oracle weblogic maven plugin to deploy an application to an admin server with administration port.
I am using t3s protocol to connect but I am wondering whether I can set my custom keystore and certs in the maven plugin/parameters
in pom.xml or command line. 
I cannot find the solution on the internet.
Help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can set the weblogic ssl headers in maven opts - like so
-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=CustomTrust -Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName=

But the plugin doesn't seem to pick these up where as the weblogic.Deployer will.  This is a little odd since the maven plugin just runs the deployer anyway.

I've also tried setting the java keystore to a custom one (also with no luck)

Answer (score 0):

well the question is like "old" :) - but it seems there is no conclusive answer around and since this question pops up at google in the top10 here is what I did to make the maven -> weblogic deployment work

**Using:** maven 3.2.3 to deploy to WLS 12.1.3 and the WLS 12.1.3 DEV (Do not forget to execute the configure script prior to starting - well - anything)

**Setup (done once)**

Follow the [Oracle Docs for the Maven Plugin](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm) to setup the plugin. In short:

Mainly you will install a maven plugin from the WLS DEV zip to install another maven plugin:

```
cd %WL_HOME%\oracle_common\plugins\maven\com\oracle\maven\oracle-maven-sync\12.1.3

mvn install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3.jar
```

install the plugin to be used to deploy:

```
mvn com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -DoracleHome=%WL_HOME%
```

Verify the plugin is ok:

```
mvn help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=weblogic-maven-plugin -Dversion=12.1.3-0-0
```

If you need this to be added to a Maven repository proxy you can temporarily change the path to your local repository, executes those commands and that's what will be required (around 230MB in my case). I would add another thirdparty repository on the maven proxy and put everything in there in case you need to clean up later.

Then use the [InstallCert](https://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java) tool to import the SSL certificate into a new keystore. We will place this keystore in the maven module that creates the EAR file and executes the deployment.

**Deployment**

Once you have your EAR file ready you need to add this to your build section:
(not the SSL / keystore messing around is only required when using t3s, you obviously skip the property setting if there is no self-signed certificate involved)

The "TrustKeyStore=CustomStore" parameter is somehow required! The name must not be changed.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <weblogic.security.TrustKeyStore>CustomTrust</weblogic.security.TrustKeyStore>
                    <weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName>${basedir}/src/main/keystore/cacerts.dev.jks</weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName>
                    <weblogic.security.TrustKeystoreType>JKS</weblogic.security.TrustKeystoreType>
                    <weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase>changeit</weblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStorePassPhrase>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
            <configuration>
                <adminurl>t3s://HOSTNAME_HERE:7101</adminurl>
                <user>WLS-USER-IN-DEPLYOERS-GROUP</user>
                <password>WLS-USER-PASSWORD</password>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
                <targets>TARGET_SERVERNAME_IN_WLS_TO_DEPLOY_TO</targets>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <name>YouApplicationName</name>
                <remote>true</remote>
                <upload>true</upload>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wls-deploy-dev</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The above configuration will deploy the EAR during install phase - feel free to change to phase of the weblogic-maven-plugin. It could also be in a profile I guess.

Happy Deploying :)

**Links:**

- [weblogic.Deployer command line reference](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DEPGD/wldeployer.htm)
- [Docummentation of the WLS maven plugin](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm)
- [Properties Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html)
- [InstallCert Tool](https://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java)